# Is it possible to override a method's return value with a different type parameter in a subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, list, overriding

Is it possible, when overriding a `List` to change the type? Provided that it is compatible?

*Example:*

```
public class Base
{
     public virtual List<Object> SomeList { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
     public override List<Bar> SomeList { get; set; }
}
```

If not, is there an easy solution to this problem?

As for what I'd like to do: I want to have a base class that will serve as an implementation (Cannot be an interface however) for a client and server class which will have their own properties. The client and server will have different versions of the `Bar` class, so they need to have their own lists.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: No, you can't do that. If a method accepts parameter of type `Base`, and you pass a `Foo` (legally, of course), what happens when it tries to add a `Baz` object to the list (because it thinks it's a `List<Object>`)?

Comment: Have you considered generics? If yes: why did you not go for them?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. For what you want it would be feasible, if you use a generic property.

```
public class Base<T>
{
    public List<T> { get; set; }
}
```

Then you `Foo` class would be:

```
public class Foo : Base<Bar>
{

}
```

This way you derived class, called `Foo`, would have access to a list of type `Bar`, which
will be declared to it's base class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible but depending on what you want to achieve you could use an interface as List type in your example.